# decrease the opacity js

Tags: javascript, css, opacity, fadeout

I'm trying to decrease he opacity of an image while scrolling.
It should be like fade out

```
var scrollPercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);

 if(scrollPercent < 0.25){
         var myImage3 = document.getElementById('wheat-image-main3');
         myImage3.style.opacity = '1'
     }
    
     if(scrollPercent > 0.25){
         var myImage3 = document.getElementById('wheat-image-main3');
         myImage3.style.opacity = '0'
     }
```

Comment: Have you checked out the scroll percentage value?

Comment: The opacity can be a number from 0 to 1. So not '0' or '1' you can also set `0.5` (no `'` then). You can just set it to any float value 0.0 to 1.0. See [opacity documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity). Is the scrollPercent even a good value? I would use the top corner of the myImage3 element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to wrap it in a scroll event listener and it'll work:

```js
const myImage3 = document.getElementById('wheat-image-main3');

document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    var scrollPercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);

 if(scrollPercent < 0.25){
         myImage3.style.opacity = '1'
     }
    
     if(scrollPercent > 0.25){
         myImage3.style.opacity = '0'
     }
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}

#wheat-image-main3 {
  transition: opacity 125ms ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<img id="wheat-image-main3" src="//placehold.it/200/200" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add scroll event listener.

```
addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
if(scrollPercent < 0.25){
         var myImage3 = document.getElementById('wheat-image-main3');
         myImage3.style.opacity = '1'
     }
    
     if(scrollPercent > 0.25){
         var myImage3 = document.getElementById('wheat-image-main3');
         myImage3.style.opacity = '0'
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen the scroll events to get this work. Below is an example, but you can achieve this working with CSS class as well and classList property.

```js
const img = document.querySelector('.image')

document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    if(this.scrollY >= 100) {
        img.style.opacity = "0.5"
    }
    else {
        img.style.opacity = "1"
    }
})
```

```html
<img src="" height="500" class="image" />
```